# jpa not started with websphere - NoClassDefFoundError: CandidateComponentsIndexLoader?

Tags: spring, jpa, websphere

There is spring 4.3.0 application + jpa + jaxb

So, I need to start this application on websphere server.
My application consist of main class - [WebApplicationInitializer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)
There 3 layers - web(controllers with WebConfig), service(ServiceConfig) and persisntence(PersistenceConfig)

After I add PersistenceConfig in application - there is error message on WAS server(there is no such problems on tomcat server)

My PersisntenceConfig:

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"data.persistence"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"data.persistence"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES = "ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String DO_NOT_AUDIT_LOCKING_FIELD = "org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
        entityManager.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    //Set properties hibernate
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field",
                env.getRequiredProperty(DO_NOT_AUDIT_LOCKING_FIELD));

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Error message is :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.setResourceLoader(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:431)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setResourceLoader(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:320)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:112)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>           ... 113 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
>           at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:924)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:869)
>           at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
>           ... 120 more
>
> [12/11/18 14:10:06:443 MSK] 00000079 webapp        I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [MyApp_war#MyApp.war]:.Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   [12/11/18 14:10:06:445 MSK] 00000079 webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E:
>   Failure to initialize Web application MyApp.war [12/11/18 14:10:06:447
>   MSK] 00000079 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, MyApp.war, of
>   application, MyApp_war.ear/deployments/MyApp_war, failed to start
>   [12/11/18 14:10:06:448 MSK] 00000079 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An
>   error occurred starting, MyApp_war [12/11/18 14:10:06:448 MSK]
>   00000079 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: MyApp_war
>   [12/11/18 14:10:06:455 MSK] 00000079 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I:
>   Application stopped: MyApp_war [12/11/18 14:10:06:457 MSK] 00000079
>   CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit
>   WebSphere:cuname=MyApp_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApp_war failed
>   to start. [12/11/18 14:10:06:461 MSK] 00000079 MBeanHelper   E   Could
>   not invoke an operation on object:
>   WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=pega-wasNode01,version=8.5.5.13,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=pega-wasNode01Cell,spec=1.0
>   because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to
>   load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Error creating bean with name
>   &#39;entityManagerFactory&#39; defined in
>   data.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Initialization of bean
>   failed&#59; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader

Comment: You have mixed spring versions, the `CandidateComponentsIndexLoader` is a Spring 5 class. So something is making that you are mixing different versions of spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, can you create answer instead comment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [`org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader.html) is a introduced in Spring Framework 5.0. You state you are using Spring Framework 4.3.

The logical conclusion is you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring. As a rule of thumb never mix jars from different versions of a framework.